# Exercise on Fundamentals of Divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

(This question is on page 236 of Falko Lorenz's Algebra Volume 1: Fields and Galois Theory, exercise 4.5)

> Prove that $Y^2 = X^3 - 2$ has exactly one solution in the natural numbers.

Hint: use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a Euclidean domain, and that in any unique factorization domain $R$, if $\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_n$ are pairwise rel. prime in $R$ and their product is an $m$-th power in $R$, each $\alpha_i$ is associated to an $m$-th power in $R$.

Here's what I know. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a Euclidean domain, then it is also a unique factorization domain. As well, $X^3=Y^2+2=Y^2-\sqrt{-2}^2=(Y-\sqrt{-2})(Y+\sqrt{-2})$. Clues for the clueless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**An outline:** The units are $\pm 1$.  Show that $X$ and $Y$ must be odd. Then show $Y+\sqrt{-2}$ and $Y-\sqrt{-2}$ are relatively prime. So each is a cube.

Let $Y+\sqrt{-2}=(a+b\sqrt{-2})^3$. Expand. Compute in particular the coefficient of $\sqrt{-2}$. This must be $1$. That will tell you something very important about $b$. But then you will know what $a$ must be, more or less. That will give the only solutions, and the only positive one.

Comment: Ok I got that $1=3a^2b-2b^3$. I'm confused about what this should be telling me?

Comment: That $b$ divides $1$!

Comment: Oh grief, thank you : )

Comment: Well I got it, $X=3$ and $Y=5$!

Comment: OK, but remember there are (deliberately) little missing steps in my outline. Little proofs to fill in. Like what are the units? (Norm argument) Any solutions must be odd (easy). $X+\sqrt{-2}$ and its conjugate are relatively prime in the ring. For that I used fact that solutions are odd.

Comment: Yup, I proved the units (its actually part of the exercise before) and I showed by contradiction that any solutions must be odd, and then using this, I showed that any element which divides $(Y+\sqrt{-2})$ and $(Y-\sqrt{-2})$, must be even and divide $X^3$, contradiction. And I think you mean that $Y+\sqrt{-2}$ and its conjugate are rel. prime.

Comment: Yes, mistyped. Usually manage to proofread answers, but comments, well, not so much.